# How to password protect the domain with htaccess?

Tags: unix, .htaccess, password, website

This is not the usual request.

I need to protect a domain while keeping the inner files accessible.

So my HTACCESS file at the domain's root FTP folder is as follows:

```
 AuthType   basic
 AuthName   "Secure"
 AuthUserFile   /path/to/my/password/.ok_pass
 <Files index.html>
 Require    valid-user
 </Files>
```

This password protects my site if I visit it like this: `www.mydomain.com/index.html` but not when I visit it directly like `www.mydomain.com`.

So how do I set a password to the default document in a directory?

Answer (score 1):

So, you want it to require a password for / and /index.html but not anything else?

Add:

```
<Location />
Require valid-user
</Location>
```

Comment: Its not working, instead returning a 500 Server Internal error. Apparently the syntax is bad. Can we try anything else?

Comment: You cannot add <Location> directives within .htaccess files

Comment: Do you have access to the Apache config to set it there (or can you get your webhost to do it)?

Answer (score 0):

It's an unusual request, but I think you'd have to password-protect the entire root directory and then override that for all the contents. Overriding it lower down to allow everyone could be tricky and it's something I've never done before, but this might work:

```
<Directory /root/of/your/site>
    Require valid-user

    <Files index.html otherfile.html etc>
        Allow from all
        Satisfy Any
    </Files>

    <Directory subdir>
        Allow from all
        Satisfy Any
    </Files>
</Directory>
```